# Could not find package Symfony/skeleton with stability Stable in a version installable using your PHP version 7.0.2

Tags: symfony4

I am new to Symfony skeleton. Can anyone please help to get out from this error for installation of Symfony?

php -v command  give :  7.2.12( ubuntu 16.04)

when i execute this command : 
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton myProject, i have this error :

Could not find package Symfony/skeleton with stability Stable in a version installable using your PHP version 7.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that in your composer.json is a wrong php version defined as config or require:

```
"require": {
    "php": "7.0.2"
},
"config": {
  "platform": {
        "php": "7.0.2"
    }
}
```

Just change these to ^7.0.2 instead. That would mean you application can run on 7.0.2 and upwards.